# Number of 2n-digit binary sequences

Tags: combinatorics, binary

Find the number of 2n-digit binary sequences in which the number of 0's in the first n digits is equal to the number of 1's in the last n digits.

I'm not sure how to approach the question.

My thoughts:

1) Find the total number of permutations of a 2n-digit binary sequence which is $2^{2n}$.

The answer given is $\binom{2n}{n}$

Comment: Hint: How many 0's in the binary sequence altogether?

Comment: Is it $\binom{2n}{n}$ which is the answer to my question?

Comment: The conditions of your problem tell exactly how many 0's and 1's there are in each 2n-bit sequence.  Think about the number of 0's in the first half, plus the number of them in the second half.

Comment: Yup, I think I see it. The number of 0's in the first half + the number of 0's in the second half is n. Thanks!

Comment: This might be a suitable occasion for you to write an Answer to your own Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number of 0's in the first n digits are equal to the number of 1's in the last n digits, that also means that the number of 0's and 1's are equal in the 2n-digit binary sequence. That would mean the total number of binary sequences with n 0's and n 1's would be $\binom{2n}{n}$.